# How do I flip a selected area of a layer using JavaScript script in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

So I am writing a script for Photoshop (using JavaScript) and I want it to select a marquee area and then invert the colors of that area and then flip that area upside down (vertically).

I tried doing:

```js
doc.artLayers["Layer 1"].resize(1, doc.height * -1)
```

However this transforms the entire layer instead of just the selected area and adding `.selection` in there just returns an error. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the parent of `selection` is `document` not `artLayer`:

```
app.activeDocument.selection.resize(undefined, -100, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
```